# Generate Shapeless Record from Generics

Tags: scala, generics, shapeless

I have this standard `Shapeless` code:

```
case class KeyValue(key: String, value: Int)
val kv = KeyValue("key", 1)

def processCaseClass(p: KeyValue) = {
     val gen = LabelledGeneric[KeyValue] 
     gen.to(p)
}
```

But instead of using the name of the case class, I'd like to use generics, however, rewriting it this way, does not work:

```
def processCaseClass[KV <: Product, L <: HList](p: KV) = {
     val gen = LabelledGeneric.Aux[KV, L] 
     gen.to(p)
}
```

If I change `gen` to an implicit parameter it works OK.

What is wrong with the above code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Making a method generic in `T` makes it clueless as to what `T` is. If `processCaseClass` doesn't know what `KV` *is*, it stands no chance of analyzing its structure enough to make a `LabelledGeneric[KV]`, producing an implicit resolution error. By making it an implicit parameter, you shift the responsibility of producing the `LabelledGeneric` to the caller, where it actually stands a chance of being satisfied, because the caller will know what `PK` is.

An odd thing that your first definition of `processCaseClass` does is this, which should suffice to show that it cannot be correct:

```
def processCaseClass[KV <: Product, L <: HList](p: KV): Any // Signature of pCC
// Function body doesn't affect sig., aside from return type, so what you write is what you get
// A sig. is the only interface between a method and the world. This method doesn't
// say there's a relationship between KV and L in its signature, so there doesn't
// need to be one.

// Instantiate KV = (Int, Int), L = String :: String :: HNil, p = (5, 5)
val x = processCaseClass[(Int, Int), String :: String :: HNil]((5, 5))
// Perfectly valid to the compiler... but what is this supposed to do?
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Now it makes sense.